# authenticationManager doesnt check a password

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, spring-security

I have one valid user in my mysql table, with username = alex and password = 123.
So when i try to logIn with wrong usernames such as bob,fred,pit etc. all works
and i receive authentication error.
But when i try to authenticate with valid username = alex , no matter what password i enter, it will be "123" or "213" or "12afaf12" , i always recieve succesfull logIn. I think what authentication manager doesnt check a password. Can you help me?
There is my source:

**security-config.xml**

```
 <security:http auto-config="true">
       <security:form-login 
            login-page="/login.xhtml" 
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed.xhtml" 
            default-target-url="/succes.xhtml"  
       />
       <security:logout 
            logout-url="/app/logout"
            logout-success-url="/app/main"
       />
</security:http>
<security:authentication-manager>
            <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
                  <!--    <security:password-encoder hash="md5" />-->
            </security:authentication-provider>
```

```
 <bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
            <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService" />
            <property name="hideUserNotFoundExceptions" value="false" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
            <constructor-arg>
                    <ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
            </constructor-arg>
 </bean>
```

**custom UserDetailsService class**

```
import com.app.dao.UserDao;
import com.app.model.UserEntity;
import com.app.service.intf.UserServiceIntf;


@Service("userService")
public class UserService implements UserServiceIntf, UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    /**
     * Construct UserDetails instance required by spring security
     */
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

            UserEntity user = userDao.loadUserByUserName(userName);

            if (user == null) {
                    throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format(getMessageBundle().getString("badCredentials"), userName));

            }

            Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
            System.out.println("user.getUserName()"+ user.getUserName());
            User userDetails = new User(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
            return userDetails;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves full User record from database by user name
     * 
     * @param userName
     * @return UserEntity
     */
    public UserEntity loadUserEntityByUsername(String userName) {
            return userDao.loadUserByUserName(userName);
    }



    public UserDao getUserDao() {
            return userDao;
    }

    public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
            this.userDao = userDao;
    }

}
```

**userDao**

```
@Repository
public class UserDao implements UserDaoIntf {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}

public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
         this.entityManager = entityManager;
}


/**
 * Queries user by username
 * 
 * @param userName
 * @return User entity
 */
public UserEntity loadUserByUserName(String userName) {
        Assert.notNull(userName);
        UserEntity user = null;
        Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("select u from UserEntity"
                        + " u where u.userName = :userName").setParameter("userName", userName);
        try {
                user = (UserEntity) query.getSingleResult();
        } catch(NoResultException e) {
                //do nothing
        }

        return user;
}

}
```

**authentication service:**

```
@Service("userAuthenticationProviderServiceImpl")
public class UserAuthenticationProviderServiceImpl implements      UserAuthenticationProviderService {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    /**
     * Process user authentication
     * 
     * @param user
     * @return
     */
    public boolean processUserAuthentication(UserEntity user) {    
        try {
                Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword());
                Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(request);

                if (authenticate.isAuthenticated()) {
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticate);  

                    return true;
                }

        } catch(AuthenticationException e) {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, 
                                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, e.getMessage(), "Sorry!"));              
        }
       return false;
    }

    public AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager() {
            return authenticationManager;
    }

    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
            this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

}
```

I think problem in **authenticate.isAuthenticated()** always return true with no matter what password i enter, if username valid

**UPDATE1:**
ADD MY USER ENTITY

```
@Entity
@Table(name="appuser")
public class UserEntity  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String userName;
    private String password;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
            return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
            PasswordEncoder crypto = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
            this.password = crypto.encodePassword(password, null);
    }

}
```

**UserManagedBean**

```
@Component
@ViewScoped
public class UserManagedBean {

 public UserManagedBean(){
     System.out.println("Just for test, usermanagedbean nstantiated");
 }
 @Inject
 private UserService userService;

 @Inject 
 private UserAuthenticationProviderServiceImpl userAuth;

 private UserEntity user;

private String userName;
private String password;
private String isAuth;

public UserEntity getUser() {
     return user;
}

public void setUser(UserEntity user) {
     this.user = user;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public String getIsAuth() {
    return isAuth;
}

public void setIsAuth(String isAuth) {
    this.isAuth = isAuth;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String doLogin() {
    UserEntity user = userService.loadUserEntityByUsername(userName);
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();  

    if (user == null){
        System.out.println("user == null");

        context.addMessage("somekey", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Invalid Username or Password", "Invalid username or Password"));  
        return null;    
    }

    boolean result =  userAuth.processUserAuthentication(user);

    if (result) {
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Login Info", "Succesfully login!"));
        isAuthenticated();
        return "OK";
    } else {
        System.out.println("ERRRROR");
    }
    return null;
}

public void isAuthenticated() {
     if(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null &&
             SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated()){
         setIsAuth("OK");

     }
}



}
```

**login page:**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            template="/WEB-INF/templates/general.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="title"><h:outputText value="Please Sign In" /></ui:define>
    <ui:define name="header"><h:outputText value="Please Sign In" /></ui:define>


     <ui:define name="content">
         <h:form id="loginForm" prependId="false">
                 <p:fieldset styleClass="fieldset" legend="Authentication Form">
                         <p:focus />
                         <p:messages id="messages" for="somekey" />

                         <p:growl id="growlMessages" showDetail="true" sticky="true" life="13000" globalOnly="true"/>   

                         <h:panelGrid id="logPanelGrid" style="margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 25px; text-align: right" cellspacing="8" columns="3">
                                    <h:panelGroup>
                                            <h:outputText value="User Name:" />
                                            <h:outputText style="color:red" value="*  " />
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                    <p:inputText id="userName" value="#{userManagedBean.userName}" required="true" label="User Name" title="Enter your User Name!" />
                                    <h:panelGroup>
                                            <p:message id="userNameMsg" for="userName" />
                                            <p:tooltip for="userName" styleClass="tooltip" showEvent="focus" hideEvent="blur" />
                                    </h:panelGroup>

                                    <h:panelGroup>
                                            <h:outputText value="Enter Password:" />
                                            <h:outputText style="color:red" value="*  " />
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                    <p:password id="pass" value="#{userManagedBean.password}" required="true" label="Password" title="Please enter a password!" />
                                    <h:panelGroup>
                                            <p:message id="passMsg" for="pass" />
                                            <p:tooltip for="pass" styleClass="tooltip" showEvent="focus" hideEvent="blur" />
                                    </h:panelGroup>


                                 <p:commandButton id="newUserButton" action="newUser"  icon="ui-icon-plus" value="Sign Up" />
                                 <p:commandButton id="submitButton" update="growlMessages,messages" action="#{userManagedBean.doLogin()}"  value="SignIn" />

                         </h:panelGrid>
                 </p:fieldset>
         </h:form>
    </ui:define>
```

**UPDATE 2: SOLVED**
I solved my problem by replacing thats code in my **UserManagedBean**

```
UserEntity user = userService.loadUserEntityByUsername(userName);
```

with

```
UserEntity user = new UserEntity(); 
user.setPassword(password); 
user.setUserName(userName);
```

What do you think about it?

Comment: Can you post your User class source?

Comment: thx for your comment, i added my user entity to my post, can you help me now?

Comment: What is `userAuthenticationProviderServiceImpl` for ?

Comment: good question , i think for nothing, its just for processUserAuthentication(UserEntity user) method , in future i bring them in  my ManagedBean, and call them directly from my login.xhtml page(update my post,added UserManagedBean and login page)

Comment: You think it's for nothing? That's not very reassuring :-). Perhaps you should put some logging in and see if it's called... It's not clear to me what your app is doing and I don't know a lot about JSF. I'd recommend you stick with a standard (non-JSF) setup for the authentication part until you have that working.

Comment: The User class I need to see is from this line: User userDetails = new User(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword(), authorities);

Comment: @MattJennings That's most likely [the standard Spring Security User class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.java).

Comment: you're right.
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

Comment: So it is, in that case, I'm not sure what's wrong.  I haven't done things that way, typically I would implement UserDetails in the UserEntity class so I could return that directly.  You would then be able to set some breakpoints in getPassword().  Beyond that I guess I'm not much help.

Comment: i added loggin to my code and see what whatever i enter in password field , user.getPassword() from UserService class always return my valid pass 123 , and i think thats why my pass always valid ?

Comment: I solved my problem by replacing thats code in  my UserManagedBean
UserEntity user  = userService.loadUserEntityByUsername(userName);
with           
                UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
  user.setPassword(password);
  user.setUserName(userName);
What do you think about it?